# What is the number of people from Varnas required to form a government in the Mahabharata?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, history

I had watched a video of Jaipur Dialogues on YouTube some time back. It is difficult for me to go through all the videos again. In that video it was mentioned that -

w number of Brahmins
x number of Kshatriyas
y number of Vaishyas
z number of Shudras

are mentioned as the ideal set of people to form, rule and administrate over a government. It was said that this detail was mentioned in the Mahabharata. Can anyone please tell me what the numbers for w, x, y, and z are?

Comment: Are you sure - they talk about the "government" in the present form which we have these days? -I don't think so!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: @Vivikta Thanks for the welcome. Government or Kingdom or Monarchial state. That's what I meant. All I remember that the total number of people required was 36 or something around that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the reference from Mahabharata.

> Bhishma said, "Thou art endued with great intelligence, O
> Yudhishthira! It is even so as thou sayest. The person is very rare
> who is possessed of all those good qualities. To be brief, conduct
> like this (viz., the presence of all the virtues spoken of), is very
> difficult to be met with even upon careful search. **I shall, however,
> tell thee what kinds of ministers should be appointed by thee. Four
> Brahmanas, learned in the Vedas, possessed of a sense of dignity,
> belonging to the Snataka order, and of pure behaviour, and eight
> Kshatriyas, all of whom should be possessed of physical strength and
> capable of wielding weapons, and one and twenty Vaisyas, all of whom
> should be possessed of wealth, and three Sudras, every one of whom
> should be humble and of pure conduct and devoted to his daily duties,
> and one man of the Suta caste, possessed of a knowledge of the Puranas
> and the eight cardinal virtues, should be thy ministers**. Every one
> of them should be fifty years of age, possessed of a sense of dignity,
> free from envy, conversant with the Srutis and the Smritis, humble,
> impartial, competent to readily decide in the midst of disputants
> urging different courses of action, free from covetousness, and from
> the seven dreadful vices called Vyasanas. The king should consult with
> those eight ministers and hold the lead among them. He should then
> publish in his kingdom, for the information of his subjects, the
> results of such deliberation.(MB Shanti Parva 85)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so very much!

Comment: Please do upvote and accept my answer if it helped @DragonDroid